# Does JINT support TypeScript

Tags: wpf, jint

We need to write Java script functions and call them from WPF application using Jint.

We would like to move to Typescript as it  is a Superset of JavaScript which primarily provides optional static typing, classes and interfaces.

Is it possible to use TypeScript instead of javascript with Jint? If so, will there be any challenges?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you can transpile your TypeScript program to ES5 then it will work. But Jint or any other Javascript interpreter doesn't understand TS natively.

Comment: Can't beat an receiving an answer straight from the source. @user2401749 needs to mark this as the answer.